# Pass argument in class method (+) of Objective-C class from Swift class

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, arguments

I am working with hybrid project of combination of Obj-C classes and Swift classes. I am little confuse at some point.

The scenario is like this, i have one Obj-C class call Util.h which have some class methods like bellow code

```
+ (id)dict_TO_Object:(NSDictionary *)dbData withObject:(Class)myObj {
      //Some code
      return obj;
}
```

Now, i have one Swift class called `LoginVC.Swift`. In this call i want to call `dict_TO_Object` method bellow is the code

```
let tmpDict:NSMutableDictionary
someVar = Util.dict_TO_Object(tmpDict as [NSObject : AnyObject], withObject: User.self())

//Above line give me an error
Error : Cannot invoke 'dict_TO_Object' with an argument list of type '([NSObject : AnyObject], withObject: User)'
```

in above code i am passing `tmpDict` and `User` as a class which is `User.h` in Obj-c

Please suggest me a solution or modification.

**Edit:**
Tried bellow codes but get same error

```
someVar = Util.dict_TO_Object(tmpDict as NSDictionary, withObject: User().self)
```

**Edit Solution:**

Actually this method returns me an object of `User.h` class, but my variable did not understand that. See solution bellow

```
someVar = Util.dict_TO_Object(responseDict as [NSObject : AnyObject], withObject: User.self) as! User
```

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter has type `Class`, which bridges to `AnyClass` in Swift.

You need to pass `User.self`. Not `User.self()` (which is the same as `User()`), and not `User().self` (which doesn't make sense).